# No SSL certificate needed for HTTPS in cURL PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing a simple cURL script to request data from a website (https://openweathermap.org) which is HTTPS.

Basically, we need to configure curl instance to deal with SSL-enabled websites, through something like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_CAINFO, "path/to/cert");
```

However, I tried at first to make a request using the [testing URL](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02) provided by openweathermap.

```
<?php
$ressource = curl_init("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02");

$data = curl_exec($ressource);
curl_close($ressource);
```

Normally, I would have an error like: **Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

Instead, the request works perfectly:

[image]

Is it supposed to work and not return an error by not providing an SSL certificate when requesting an HTTPS URL?
Did I miss something about requesting HTTPS URLs via cURL?

Comment: The `samples.openweathermap.org` certificate is signed by an authority trusted by cURL. You need to add certificates only if the server you are connecting to requires client side certificates, i.e., for authentication, or you need to add an additional CA if the certificate on the server is not signed by a CA trusted by the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I assume that this doesn't represent a security flaw as would be the case by disabling SSL verification through something like this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0) ?

Comment: curl (as used from within PHP) has a default CA bundle of trusted CAs. That's what used when you don't specify any other.

Comment: _VERIFYPEER_ validates that when you request _samples.openweathermap.org_, the certificate returned is actually for that domain. If somebody were to try to MITM your connection and serve their own certificate instead, you might not catch this if you are not verifying the certificate actually matches the server you think you are talking to. You should leave _VERIFYPEER_ enabled unless you are intentionally serving the wrong certificate for the domain name.

Comment: Thank you guys for those explanations!